# Rails: Routing error when rendering AJAX partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am encountering a routing error when I try to render a partial in an ajax call:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"relationships", :user_id=>#<User id: 2, username: .....
```

Within my app, I have a list of followers for a user displayed on the profile page. Instead of paginating the followers, I would like to try to return the next offset of followers from the server through AJAX. My view already utilizes partials for displaying a list of these followers (limited to 5 records).

My goal is to use an AJAX call to return this partial with the next offset of records formated (I haven't implemented the functionality to return offset records yet - I'm just trying to get the ajax working first). The partials work fine when I visit the profile page in my browser (and view the first 5 records), the error occurs when I make the AJAX call.

Here is the form in the view where the ajax call originates:

```
<%= form_tag user_relationships_path(@user), method: :get, remote: true do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'load more...' %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the route:

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy, :index]
end
```

Here is my controller action (`relationships#index`) which responds to the request:

```
def index
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'load_followers' }
  end
end
```

The load_followers.js.erb partial:

```
$('ul#followers').append("<%= render 'users/following_items', users: @user.followers %>")
```

The users/following_items.html.erb partial:

```
<% users.each do |user| %>
<li class="clearfix">
    <div class="box-gravatar pull-left">
       <%= link_to user do %>
       <%= gravatar_for user, 40 %>
       <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
       <%= render 'relationships/follow', user: user %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to user.username, user %>
    <div class="box-author">joined <%= join_date_for user %></div>
</li>
<% end %>
```

And finally the relationships/follow.html.erb partial:

```
<% unless current_user?(user) %>
   <% if current_user.following? user %>
      <p><%= link_to 'unfollow', user_relationship_path(user), method: :delete, class: "btn" %></p>
   <% else %>
      <p><%= link_to 'follow', user_relationships_path(user), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have tracked down the offending code to the relationships/follow.html.erb partial. When that is removed, the ajax call works fine and the partial is appended to the end of the `ul`. Clearly it has to do with rails having an issue with the `link_to` to the `relationships#destroy` method - however, nothing I've tried seems to work.

Edit: Here are the results of running `rake routes`:

```
root        /                                                posts#index
            posts_test        /posts/test(.:format)                            posts#test
                submit        /submit(.:format)                                posts#new
                signup        /signup(.:format)                                users#new
                 login        /login(.:format)                                 sessions#new
                logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                                sessions#destroy
                 about        /about(.:format)                                 about#index
                search        /search(.:format)                                search#index
              sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                              sessions#create
           new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                          sessions#new
               session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                          sessions#destroy
         post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)               comments#create
            post_votes POST   /posts/:post_id/votes(.:format)                  votes#create
                 posts GET    /posts(.:format)                                 posts#index
                       POST   /posts(.:format)                                 posts#create
              new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                             posts#new
                  post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                             posts#show
    user_relationships GET    /users/:user_id/relationships(.:format)          relationships#index
                       POST   /users/:user_id/relationships(.:format)          relationships#create
 new_user_relationship GET    /users/:user_id/relationships/new(.:format)      relationships#new
edit_user_relationship GET    /users/:user_id/relationships/:id/edit(.:format) relationships#edit
     user_relationship GET    /users/:user_id/relationships/:id(.:format)      relationships#show
                       PUT    /users/:user_id/relationships/:id(.:format)      relationships#update
                       DELETE /users/:user_id/relationships/:id(.:format)      relationships#destroy
                 users GET    /users(.:format)                                 users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)                                 users#create
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                             users#new
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                        users#edit
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                             users#show
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                             users#update
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                             users#destroy
            categories GET    /categories(.:format)                            categories#index
                       POST   /categories(.:format)                            categories#create
          new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                        categories#new
              category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                        categories#show
                              /:category(.:format)                             posts#index
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you change `resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy, :index]` to `resources :relationships` does the delete work as expected?

Comment: Could you post the results of `rake routes` for users and relationships resources?

Comment: @Cyle - I changed the routes as specified, restarted the server, but got the same error.

Comment: @mmichael - I just added the results of `rake routes` - hope that helps narrow things down, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notices your rake routes outputted this line:

```
DELETE /users/:user_id/relationships/:id(.:format)
```

This means your named route user_relationship is expecting both `user` and `relationship` IDs. Reason being, `relationship` is a nested resource of `user`.

So for instance you currently have this in your link to:

```
= link_to 'unfollow', user_relationship_path(user), method: :delete, class: "btn"
```

Instead it should be something like:

```
= link_to 'unfollow', user_relationship_path(user, relationship), method: :delete, class: "btn"
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I was typing the exact same thing as @Cyle posted this, haha. To specify, your route for accessing the destroy action requires two parameters: user_id and relationship_id. So, as @Cyle suggested, you need something like `link_to 'unfollow', user_relationship_path(user.id, relationship)`.

Comment: @mmichael Oops, I didn't mean to steal your answer like that. Initially I thought it was a problem with the DELETE request that I encountered in the past but then I realized his link_to was off.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Not quite sure why it still worked on the non-ajax rendering. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Actually that's a very valid concern and I didn't know the answer so I tried to reproduce this myself. I started with a simple scaffolding of two models with the generic RESTful routes. On the same server instance I changed one of them to a nested resource and found that my old named routes still worked. Only after restarting the server did they break and produce a `NameError`. You might have run into the same issue, if that wasn't the case for you then I smell witchcraft as they really aught not to work!